# Form submission will not stop for validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-events

What I am trying to accomplish is a (very simple) email validation using jQuery, but no matter what I do, the form will just keep submitting.

`<form id="rfq" name="rfq" action="rfq_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`
...

`<input type="image" id="submit" name="submit" src="submit.png" border="0" />`

JS email validation:

```
//$("#rfq").submit(function() { doesnt seem to work either

$('#submit').click(function() {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    if(email.indexOf("@") == -1){
        $("#email").addClass('invalid');
        return false; // cancel form submission if email invalid
    }
    return false; // return true if no errors once i get it working
});
```

Comment: The `.submit` approach should work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/LNrqb/ -- is there any other code that might be interfering?

Comment: So what is the problem? won't submit? submits every time?

Comment: @johndavidjohn Submits every time...

Comment: Thanks everyone for your quick and thorough answers... I will work through from the top down, hopefully clear up my problem.  I'll select the best answer and upvote where appropriate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/4L4Sj/6/)

First, make sure all event handlers are attached once the DOM is **"ready"**

I'm using `.submit()` on the actual form.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // now that document is "ready"
    $('#formId').submit(function() {
        var email = $('#emailInput').val();
        alert(email);
        if(email.indexOf("@") == -1){
            alert("invalid!");
            return false; // cancel form submission if email invalid
        }
        alert("valid!");
        return true; // return true if no errors once i get it working 
    });
});
```

Comment: This is what I thought too, but the OP has a comment at the top of their code block that indicates this didn't work for them either.

Comment: Well I'm showing that in fact it does... so if this does not work, there are errors in code we have not yet seen...

Comment: Oops, that makes sense.  +1 then =)

Comment: Well, this got me up and running.  Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Try wrapping your code in a ready block.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // your code here
});
```

You should also be using the `submit` event on the `<form>` element, I think.

Comment: I'm constantly forgetting that even though my click events never run until after the page is loaded, they're still attached to selectors that won't match anything before `$(document).ready`.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to work. If you don't understand why, feel free to ask :)

```
var validated = false;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#rfq").submit(function(event) {
        if (validated === true) {
            return true;
        }
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent submission
        var email = $('#email').val();
        if(email.indexOf("@") == -1){
            $("#email").addClass('invalid');
            return;
        }
        validated = true;
        return $(this).trigger('submit');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using this function to validate your address.

```
function validateEmail(elementValue){
   var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
   return emailPattern.test(elementValue);
 }
```

And then modify your code to submit the form.

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    if(!validateEmail(email)){
        $("#email").addClass('invalid');            
    }
    else {
       $("form").submit();
    }
});
```