# Form Validation Not stopping input that is not valid.Sends user to headr location.(PHP)

Tags: php, forms, validation

I found this, [Form submission will not stop for validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637456/form-submission-will-not-stop-for-validation), but it is based of of JQUERY and not PHP. Should I not use PHP and switch?

So I have what I think to be a validated form. Problem is that if the form information is not right, my site will go ahead and forward the registrar to the next page. I will leave my form code below, and maybe you guys who are better at this than me, will have the kindness and compassion to help me as usual. After that I will show you how I am processing the information. Thanks for all you guys do. I am just very confused. Thanks again and happy 2014.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
if (empty($_POST["first_name"]))
{$first_nameErr = "Required";}
else
{
$first_name = test_input($_POST["first_name"]);
// check if name only contains letters and whitespace
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$first_name))
{
$first_nameErr = "Only letters allowed";
}
}

if (empty($_POST["last_name"]))
{$last_nameErr = "Required";}
else
{
$last_name = test_input($_POST["last_name"]);
// check if name only contains letters and whitespace
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$last_name))
{
$last_nameErr = "Only letters allowed";
}
}


if (empty($_POST["email"]))
{$emailErr = "Required";}
else
{
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
// check if e-mail address syntax is valid
if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]...
{
$emailErr = "Invalid email format";
}
}


if (empty($_POST["password"]))
{$passwordErr = "Required";}
else
{$password = test_input($_POST["password"]);}

if (empty($_POST["gender"]))
{$genderErr = "";}
else
{$gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);}

}

function test_input($data)
{
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
?>



<div class="signupitsfree" float="right">
<p class="signup">Sign Up
It's Completely Free!</p>


<form method="POST" name="signup" action="life/chickenwings.php">

<label for="first name"></label><input id="first name" name="first_name"   
placeholder="First Name" type="text" value="<?php echo $first_name;?>" /> <span 
class="error">* <?php echo $first_nameErr;?></span>

<label for="last_name"></label><input id="last name" name="last_name" 
placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="<?php echo $last_name;?>" />
<span class="error">* <?php echo $last_nameErr;?></span>
<br><br>


<label for="email"></label><input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"    
type="text" value="<?php echo $email;?>" />
<span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>





<label for="password"></label><input id="password" name="password" placeholder="Create 
Password" type="password" />
<span class="error">* <?php echo $passwordErr;?></span>



<label for="male"><strong>Male</strong></label> <input id="male" value="male" <?php if 
(isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> name="gender" type="radio" />
<label for="female"><strong>Female</strong></la... <input id="female" value="female"  
<?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> name="gender" 
type="radio" />
<span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>



<label for="submit">"I Agree To <a href="#">Terms And Conditions"</a></label> <input 
id="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" name="submit"/>


<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<hr>
```

Now is the way I am processing the information.

```
<?php

 $hostname="figureitout";
 $username="figureitout";
 $password="figureitout";
 $dbname="figureitout";

  $db_conx = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to
  connect to database! Please try again later.");

  if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
  }

 $select = mysqli_select_db($db_conx,$dbname);

 $first_name= $_POST["first_name"];
 $last_name= $_POST["last_name"];
 $email= $_POST["email"];
 $password= $_POST["password"];
 $gender= $_POST["gender"];

 mysqli_query($db_conx,"INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, password, 
 gender)
 VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$password', '$gender')");
 mysqli_close($db_conx);

 header("Location: chicken/wing.php")
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your validation code needs to be on the SECOND page, before you write the data. PHP is run on the server, so having it above the form is useless (unless the form submits to itself, in which case all this code should be on one page).

I'm not going to write the whole thing for you, but it should look like this:

```
$ errors = 0;
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
if (empty($_POST["first_name"]))
{$first_nameErr = "Required";
$errors++;}
else
{
$first_name = test_input($_POST["first_name"]);
// check if name only contains letters and whitespace
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$first_name))
{
$first_nameErr = "Only letters allowed";
$errors++;
}
}

if ($errors) {
 //display form with errors highlighted
}
else 
{
 //do your insert code
}
```

Comment: You said "display form with errors highlighted" and "Do your insert code".  When you said, "Do your insert code", was you talking about the code that inserts the info into the database? Also when you said, "Display Form Errors Highlighted", I did not understand what you meant.

Comment: Yes, if there are no errors, you would insert into the database. I mean, you wrote the code so you would know this right?  Display the  form with errors highlighted means.... show the user the form again, and apply special formatting to the errors so they can see what they did wrong... like you see on every web form ever.

Comment: I understand the inserting part.  Yes I did write the code. :)   SO the issue with showing the errors is that it does not show the errors. It just sends the registrar to the header location. So how do I show the user the form again instead of having them forwarded to the headers location. I am sorry for all this confusion but if you can stick with me for a little bit longer I think you will be able to help me.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what it is you're missing here. In the `if ($errors) {` block, put or include the code for your form. In your form should be code checking for things like `$first_nameErr` and displaying them to the user if found.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Digital Chris, if you wanted client side validation, you could use a simple jquery script similar to:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 //client side validation before submit
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var regexp = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\+\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
 $("form").submit(function() {
 if ($("input:first").val()==''){
   alert("You need a subject!");
 return false;
 } else if ($('input[name="name"]').val()==''){
   alert ("You need a name!");
   return false;
 } else if ($('input[name="email"]').val()=='' || ($('input[name="uemail"]').val().match(regexp)<1)){
    alert ("You need a value email address");
return false;
 } else {
 //if valid, send data for server side processing
 //$.ajax({url:'phpvalidation.php',type:'post'});
 alert("Your form was submitted");
 return true;
 };
 });
 });
 </script>
```

This shouldn't be considered "validated" or safe, but would be nice for users.  The PHP script should do the final validation and input cleaning. 
Cheers,